# how to cat an input file to an output file, adding a blank line between every two lines of the input file (double spacing)?

Tags: shell, input, output

Without using SED, is there shell script to copy the content from an input file to a output file, adding a blank line between every two lines of the input file (double spacing)? I

Comment: _"without using sed"_ smells like homework...

Comment: *is there shell script...* easy answer : yes.

Answer (score 0):

```
IFS=""
while read -r LINE
do
  echo "$LINE"
  echo
done
```

If it bothers you that it adds a blank line after the last line, one can do:

```
IFS=""
FIRST=y
while read -r LINE
do
  if [ "$FIRST" != "y" ]
  then
    echo
  fi
  FIRST=n
  echo "$LINE"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

This appears to achieve what you're after.

If NR (line number) is divisible by 2, tag an extra newline at the end.  And then print the line.

```
$ awk 'NR%2==0{$0=$0"\n"}1' foo.txt
line1
line2

line3
line4

line5
$
```

If it's merely a blank line between every line, use this

```
$ awk '{print $0,"\n"}' foo.txt
line1

line2

line3

line4

line5

$
```

Comment: "between every two lines" not every two lines. -1.

Comment: If?! Come on...